Web Push Notifications_Inline Replies not Working
I'm using notification with type text:
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    const data = event.data.json();
    self.registration.showNotification(data.name, {
        actions: [
            {
                action: 'reply',
                type: 'text',
                title: 'Say smth',
            }
        ],
    });
});

When noti appears and I'm pressing the btn Say smth it doesn't show me any text input field, but noti just closing.
My browser and it's vers: Yandex Browser 24.1
How to solve this issue?
I followed this instructions, but it doesn't help:
Actions (Inline Replies)
